# how can i do a PROPFIND method with httpclient on Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, httpclient, webdav, propfind

I have a freenas server with a WEBDAV sharing. 
I would like to connect my angular backoffice to the nas to get the files list on a directory.
After a long research, I didn't find how can I do an http request in angular with a PROPFIND methods.. and get my filelist in xml type.

Thank you for your help.
(sorry for my english).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `HttpClient request()` method and as a first argument place a string `'PROPFIND'`

```
 this.http.request('PROPFIND', this.WEBDAV_BASE + '/' + directoryName , { headers: headers , responseType: 'text'}).pipe(
      map(res => {
        // your code goes here, play around with 'res'
      })
      catchError(error => error);
  )
```